# Count Disctinct Items by Date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter

| Column-A | Column-B |
| --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-2024 | Banana |
| 1-Jan-2024 | Papaya |
| 1-Jan-2024 | Banana |
| 1-Jan-2024 | Pear |
| 2-Jan-2024 | Watermelon |
| 2-Jan-2024 | Papaya |
| 2-Jan-2024 | Papaya |
| 2-Jan-2024 | Watermelon |

I'd like to count distinct on `column-B`.

I'd like to put it on other cells the outcome:

```
1Jan24 == 3
2jan24 == 2
. and so on
```

Thanks

Reading from : https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/count-distinct-unique-values-excel/

I tried :

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(a2:a9,b2:b9="1-Jan-2024"))),0)
```

<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd>

Why is the outcome 0 ?

Comment: Are you using Excel or Googlesheets? They are different in many respects.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(fruit_range,date_range=target_date)))
```

? <kbd>Ctrl-Shft-Enter</kbd> not required.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, thanks

```
=countunique(Filter(b2:b9,a2:a9=today())) 

=countunique(Filter(b2:b9,a2:a9=b2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get distinct counts for all dates in the range with this formula. It will return two columns with date and number of distinct values.

```
=MAP(UNIQUE(A2:A9),LAMBDA(d, {d, COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B9, A2:A9=d)))}))
```

- `A2:A9` - range with dates.
- `B2:B9` - range with values.

Important:

1. These ranges must be of the same size (number of rows).
2. You may need to format the resulting date column as dates explicitly. By default, Google Sheets might treat it as numbers.